# initial block execution order in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have made a counter module and I can't seem to grasp the execution order of initial block for both counter module and testbench module.

As far as I know, I thought in verilog, **initial block would always be executed first.**

In this case, I'll be executing testbench module and I am assuming `initial` block
for `testbench_counter` will be executed first.

Next, I thought counter module `C` would be executed and value for `x_in` would be updated to `temp` with no need for `#1` delay in module `C`.

But without `#1`, or changing `initial` to `always@(x_in)` I see [redline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx9LG.png).

So the question is

1. would `initial` block for counter module `C`  be executed first even before the `initial` block for testbench?
2. Why does it work if i use `always@(x_in)`?

Thanks in advance.

**Code for counter**

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module counter(x_in,clk,y_out);
    input [31:0] x_in;
    input clk;
    output [31:0] y_out;
    reg [31:0] y_out;
    reg [31:0] temp;

    initial begin
        #1 temp=x_in;
    end

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        temp<=temp+1;   
        y_out<=temp;
    end
endmodule
```

**code for testbench**

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module testbench_conter();
    wire [31:0]y_out;
    wire [31:0]temp;
    reg [31:0]x_in;
    reg clk;

    counter C(x_in,clk,y_out);

    always begin
        #5 clk=~clk;
    end

    initial begin
        clk=1'b0; 
        x_in=32'd0;
        #0
        #10000
        $stop;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

> Next, I thought counter module C would be executed...

The major flaw in your thinking is that the initial statement in the counter is executed when the counter is "executed". This is not the case. **All** initial statements are run at start of the program, and only once. Thus your two initial statements form a race condition.

By using #1 or `always@(x_in)` you delay the assignment to `temp1 until after x_in is defined.

Much better would be to add a 'load' signal to your counter which picks up the value of x_in when activated.

Also your y_out is delayed by another clock cycle.

Normally a loadable counter would look like:

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
   if (load)
      y_out <= x_in;
   else
      y_out <= y_out + 1;   
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question 1: there is absolutely ne guaranteed order of execution between `initial` blocks. Verilog simulation starts them in arbitrary unpredictible order. The only way to synchronize are #delays and other wait and delay statements.

Verilog guarantees that execution of any procdeural block, (which includes initial and always blocks) will stop at a wait condition till it gets satisfied.

Verilog also guarantees that **all** initial blocks start *before* any **always** block.

Any signal specified at an alway block sensititivity list play a role of a 'delay' statement, causing the always block to wait till any of the signal values changes. It will continue execution of the block afterwards.

So, answering your second question, `always@(x_in)` will wait till the value of the signal changes.

so, in your case:

```
 initial begin    << will start execution at time '0' before any always block
    clk=1'b0;     << change value of clk from 'x' -> '1' 
    x_in=32'd0;   << change value of x_in 'x' -> '0'
    #0            << makes absolutely no sense here. It is a special statement
    #10000        << pauses execution for 10000 time units
    $stop;        << stopps execution
end
```

while the above initial block yields, the other blocks start execution.

```
initial begin     << starts execution at time 0, befor or after the block above
    #1 temp=x_in; << pauses for 1 time unit, then assigns temp
end
```

The assignment above happens while the first initial block waits #10000.

if you use the always block

```
always @(x_in)
   temp = x_in;
```

it will do assignemt when x_in changes and the first initial block starts waiting. This always block will be executed at the same cycle '0' when the signal gets chenged. It is different from the #1 which you used. In your cases the change will happen at cycle '1'.

Comment: How about the order of initial block execution within a file? Still no guarantee?

Comment: nope, there is no guarantee. All those blocks in all files start  execution at the same time and run in parallel.